# Magento Model with Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: magento, model, module

I am trying to create a model in my module that saves data and links against the customer_entity table. I have got the module saving the model without the foreign key constraint but as soon as I alter the table to include the constraint I get an integrity constraint violation exception even though I am including a customer id that exists in the customer_entity table.

Is there something extra I need to do with my model class or model resource class to get the model saving correctly?

Comment: Can you post some code (SQL could be useful as well)?

Comment: As well as the content of the foreign key constraint failure, please.

Answer (score 0):

There's too many things that could be a mitigating factor here.  At some point Magento is running some set of SQL queries that temporarily (or possibly permanently) cause a foreign key constraint.   The only way to solve this is to drop down below the Model layer and look at the actual SQL being run against your database.